# How to import Masonry (iOS) to my project?

Tags: ios, masonry-ios-osx

Which file do I need to import into my project? If I just import the "Masonry" folder, it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to import other libs?

Comment: Please provide more details asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

```
git clone https://github.com/desandro/masonry.git
```

Open your project in xcode, right click and add files to your project.

Use it with `#import "Masonry.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org). CocoaPods is the dependency manager for Objective-C projects. It has thousands of libraries and can help you scale your projects elegantly. You can import any static library using simple [Podfile](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html) and command line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use [CoacoaPods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods) is a good idea.If you use `MAC OS X`,It's very convenient to install by `terminal`

1.Install Ruby

2.input `sudo gem install cocoapods` in terminal

3.create a new project and enter the `cd /your project path(where you .xcodeproj  in it)`

4.enter `vim Podfile`

5.use vim to write down `pod 'Masonry'`

6.press `esc` and input `:wq`

7.enter `pod install`

8.open the `*.xcworkspace` and import `Masonry.h`

all in all,CocoaPos is a good tool to import framework.